# Run a line of script via a variable based on a value inside the worksheet - google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script

Here's the concept...

```
  function runthatline() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");

  var doThat = ss.getRange("A1").getValue();
  // The literal value in A1 = ss.getRange("B1").setValue("success")

  doThat

  ss.getRange("C1").setValue("success")

  // The values in both B1 and C1 should now be "success"

}
```

Am I not using the variable correctly in order to convert it into an actual line of code that can be executed within the flow of the script?

Can this even be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option may be to use [eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval), but remember you have to be careful with this function.

```
...
var doThat = ss.getRange("A1").getValue();
eval(doThat);
...
```

Comment: Interesting. Thanks William. Obviously I did some research on that function after your advice to be careful about using it, and I can see why you were wise to make mention of that. This was really more about curiosity than it was about a need, so I thank you for satisfying my curiosity. However, after reading "Don't use eval!" and "Dangerous", I can see the basis for the idiom, "Curiosity killed the cat". I'm kinda creeped-out by having asked my question now :/